# read data sqlite in android failed

Tags: java, android, sqlite, crud

I have a problem in my application,
the purpose is to read the data stored in database,
but it end up showing the unexpected value.

here is my ViewData.class

```
public class ViewData extends ListActivity {

    //inisialisasi kontroller
    private DBDataSource dataSource;

    //inisialisasi arraylist
    private ArrayList<Wiridan> values;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewdata);

        dataSource = new DBDataSource(this);
        // buka kontroller
        dataSource.open();

        // ambil semua data barang
        values = dataSource.getAllWiridan();

        // masukkan data barang ke array adapter
        ArrayAdapter<Wiridan> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);

        // set adapter pada list
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

code in DBDataSource.java for reading data

```
private Wiridan cursorToWiridan(Cursor cursor)
    {
        // buat objek barang baru
        Wiridan wiridan = new Wiridan();
        // debug LOGCAT
        Log.v("info", "The getLONG "+cursor.getLong(0));
        Log.v("info", "The setLatLng "+cursor.getString(1)+","+cursor.getInt(2));

        /* Set atribut pada objek barang dengan
         * data kursor yang diambil dari database*/
       wiridan.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
        wiridan.setJudul_wiridan(cursor.getString(1));
        wiridan.setJumlah_wiridan(cursor.getInt(2));

        //kembalikan sebagai objek barang
        return wiridan;
    }


    //mengambil semua data barang

        public ArrayList<Wiridan> getAllWiridan() {
            ArrayList<Wiridan> daftarWiridan = new ArrayList<>();

            // select all SQL query
            Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME,
                    allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

            // pindah ke data paling pertama
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            // jika masih ada data, masukkan data barang ke
            // daftar barang
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                Wiridan wiridan = cursorToWiridan(cursor);
                daftarWiridan.add(wiridan);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            // Make sure to close the cursor
            cursor.close();
            return daftarWiridan;
        }
```

And the last is my entity class Wiridan.java

```
public class Wiridan {
    private long id;
    private String judul_wiridan;
    private int jumlah_wiridan;

    public Wiridan()
    {

    }
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getJudul_wiridan() {
        return judul_wiridan;
    }


    public void setJudul_wiridan(String judul_wiridan) {
        this.judul_wiridan = judul_wiridan;
    }

    public int getJumlah_wiridan() {
        return jumlah_wiridan;
    }


    public void setJumlah_wiridan(int jumlah_wiridan) {
        this.jumlah_wiridan = jumlah_wiridan;
    }

}
```

and the result is unexpected, it just showed value of package,
 not the value i've input from ResultActivity.java
[image: Unexpected Value]

I really Appreciate your help, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Post the code for your `cursorToWiridan(...)` method.

Comment: I would say the answer from ρяσѕρєя K is on the right lines but I suspect it is to do with how you are writing the data into the database for the `judul_wiridan` column. In other words, what is being read from the database is correct but what is being written to the database is a string representing the object reference instead of the data it contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently `ArrayAdapter` adapter is calling default `toString` method of `Wiridan` class and showing object string representation.

To show  `judul_wiridan` in ListView override `toString` method in `Wiridan` class :

```
 @Override
public String toString() {
    return getJumlah_wiridan();
}
```

Or create a custom adapter by extending `ArrayAdapter` to override `getView` method:

[Customizing Android ListView Items with Custom ArrayAdapter](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter)

Comment: I suspect you're on the right lines but it's how judul_wiridan is being written to the database - what is being read from the `Cursor` is a string literal therefore it must have been written to the database incorrectly in the first place.

Comment: it worked, but how about judul_wiridan i can't insert more than one public String toString(){}

Comment: @RomiNaufal: create custom adapter

Comment: i have created but i dont understand how to retrieve values from database to item in listview using custom adapter

Comment: @RomiNaufal: Create a class to hold all values from database and then store all objects in ArrayList to use in custom adapter class

Comment: @RomiNaufal: close this question by accepting any answer and make new question with custom adapter class code

Answer (score 0):

You are passing Arraylist of User Defined Data Type(Object) in arrayadapter, not the Arraylist of String or CharSequence.

Use

```
ArrayAdapter<String>
```

And pass arraylist of string or You can
Create custom adapter, if you want to show more than 2 textViews.